# Filter call logs using Twilio .NET helper library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

Im trying to use the [Twilio Rest API](http://twilio.com/docs/api/rest) to get a list of call logs using [MVC .net](http://github.com/twilio/csharp). Using the following code, I can only get the most recent 50 calls. I would like to return all calls and filter as I choose.

```
@using Twilio;
@{
    // Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
    string sid = "AC123";
    string token = "abcd";

    // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    var client = new TwilioRestClient(sid, token);    

    // Get Recent Calls
    var calls = client.ListCalls();

    if (calls.RestException != null) 
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Error: {0}", calls.RestException.Message));
        Response.End();
    }    
}
<h1>Call Log</h1>
@foreach (var call in calls.Calls) {
    <p>Call from @call.From to @call.To at @call.StartTime of length @call.Duration</p>
}
```

How can I return all calls from the call logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Call method](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call) is returning a paged list of the calls where the [default pagesize](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) is 50.

So you need to do paging with the `ListCalls` overload which takes a `CallListRequest` where you can specify the pageNumber.

Here is an example how to page over all the calls:

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient(sid, token);    

var pageNumber = 0;
var totalPages = 1;

var allCalls = new List<Call>();

while(pageNumber < totalPages)
{
    var calls = client.ListCalls(new CallListRequest { PageNumber = pageNumber });

    if (calls.RestException != null) 
    {
         Response
             .Write(string.Format("Error: {0}", calls.RestException.Message));
         Response.End();
         break;
    }  
    allCalls.AddRange(calls.Calls);
    totalPages = calls.NumPages;
    pageNumber++;        
}
```

Comment: Thank You!! The biggest issue i was having was finding the correct syntax for what to pass ListCalls and you explained that perfectly

Comment: Do you have any idea how to return calls for a certain date range? I can return calls for a specific date, but have found no way to do so for a range...

Comment: No, it seams the current REST API doesn't support date ranges. What you can do is to go through your date range and get the calls for the given specific date...